# Cython code for adaptive binning

Tags: python, performance, signal-processing, cython, scipy

Here is my Cython code used for adaptive binning. The `calcAdaptiveBinnedRateMap` function is called from another Python script. The script is compiled using Cython but the speed I am expecting is still not great. How can I improve the speed of execution?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.morphology as ndimmor

#define sampline rate and alpha
cdef float samplingRate = 30.0
cdef double alpha = 0.0001 #skaggs and sachin use this value while Jim uses 0.001

"""
runs the iteration for adaptive binning till the criteria mentioned in Skaggs et al 1996 is met
INPUT: spike map, occupancy map, alpha, Number of occupancy (Nocc), Euclidean distance transform (dists)
OUTPUT: Nspikes (number of spikes), Nocc (occupancy count)
"""
def mexAdaptwhile(spikeMap, occMap, alpha, Nocc, dists):
    #initialize the variable
    cdef int Nspikes2 = 1
    cdef double rsq = 0
    cdef int EnoughPoints = 0
    cdef int Nspikes = 0

    #find the row and column count for occupancy map
    cdef int rowLen = int(np.shape(occMap)[0])
    cdef int colLen = int(np.shape(occMap)[1])

    #while the radius is less than 200 and enough points are not covered
    while rsq<200.00 and EnoughPoints==0:
        r = np.sqrt(rsq)
        #need to set these Nocc and Nspikes to zero, otherwise the two for loops above add the same spikes over again.
        Nspikes = 0
        Nocc = 0
        for i in range(rowLen):
            for j in range(colLen):
                #if the distance is less than radius
                if dists[i,j]<=r:
                    #add Nspikes
                    Nspikes = Nspikes + spikeMap[i,j]
                    #add occupancy
                    Nocc = Nocc +occMap[i,j]         
        #if number spikes is greater than 0, then set nspikes2 = number of spikes
        if Nspikes > 0:
            Nspikes2 = Nspikes
        #check for the condition from skaggs et al 1996
        if (alpha*alpha*Nocc*Nocc*rsq*Nspikes2 > 1):
            EnoughPoints = 1 #set the flag to end the loop
        #keep increasing the radius
        rsq = rsq + 1
        #output occupancy = occupancy
        Noccout = Nocc
    return Nspikes, Noccout


"""calculate adaptive binned rate map    
INPUT: spikemap, occupancy map (both of them just binned for 2cm/4cm no other operation applied on them)
NOTE: occupancy is still in terms of number of frames
OUTPUT: adaptive binned rate Map which is color adjusted
"""
def calcAdaptiveBinnedRateMap(spikeMap, occMap):
    #set unoccupied occupancy and spike corresponding to unoccupied position = 0
    spikeMap[0,0] = 0
    occMap[0,0] = 0

    #find the row, col index of minimum occupied and maximum occupied pixel
    row, col = np.where(occMap)
    minrow = np.min(row)
    maxrow = np.max(row)
    mincol = np.min(col)
    maxcol = np.max(col)

    #select the best fitting rectangle according to occupied area
    occMap = occMap[minrow:maxrow+1,mincol:maxcol+1]
    spikeMap = spikeMap[minrow:maxrow+1,mincol:maxcol+1]

    #matrix of zeros same size as of occupancy map
    z = np.zeros(np.shape(occMap))
    #variable to hold adaptive binned rate map value
    abrMap = np.copy(z)
    #variale to hold adaptive binned occupancy map
    abrOcc = np.copy(z)

    #check to endure if number of spikes is greater than 1
    if np.max(np.max(spikeMap))>0:
        #iterate over the values
        for x in range(int(np.shape(occMap)[1])):
            for y in range(int(np.shape(occMap)[0])):
                if occMap[y,x] > 0:
                    #pretend there's atleas 1 spike, and 1 occ.needed to avoid 0 threshold. 
                    Nspikes2 = 1
                    Nocc = occMap[y,x]
                    d = np.copy(z)
                    d[y,x] = 1
                    #computes the Euclidean distance transform of the input matrix.
                    #For each pixel in BW, the distance transform assigns a number that is the 
                    #distance between that pixel and the nearest nonzero pixel of BW. 
                    dists = ndimmor.distance_transform_edt(d==0)
                    # function to keep on iterating while the condition mentioned in Skaggs et al 1996 is met
                    Nspikes, Nocc = mexAdaptwhile(spikeMap, occMap, alpha, Nocc, dists)
                    if Nocc < 12: #occupancy cutoff = 0.4seconds 
                        #if less than 0.4 seconds set it to 0
                        abrMap[y,x] = 0
                        abrOcc[y,x] = 0
                    else:
                        #else equal to number of spikes/occupancy map
                        abrMap[y,x] = samplingRate*float(Nspikes)/float(Nocc)
                        #adaptive binned ocuupancy map = nocc
                        abrOcc[y,x] = Nocc

    #find the maximum value of adaptive binned rate map
    cmax = np.max(np.max(abrMap))
    if cmax > 0:
        #minimum = maximum value found above/60
        cmin = -(cmax/60.0);
    else:
        cmin = -1;
    #set adaptive binned rate map = cmin wherever adaptive binned occupancy map = 0 
    abrMap[abrOcc==0] = cmin

    #return the adaptive binned rate map
    return abrMap
```

Comment: _the speed I am expecting is still not great, How can I improve the speed of execution?_ - What does this exactly mean? How many days does this function need to complete and to how many days would be optimal for it to run?

Comment: Please update the title so it describes what the code is doing.

Comment: Crosspost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/42324609

Comment: Did you profile your code?

Comment: I am still a learner, will do the profiling asap and get back

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to declare all variables with Cython (otherwise the lines with such variables basically run with Python-speed). Especially important for the "for"-loop variables (i.e. `i`, `j`, `x`, `y`).

One can also use `cython -a mycode.pyx` to create an annotated HTML page that shows, which lines are running with C or Python speed, respectively.